# Replace an item in an array that doesn't match any item in another array with a specific value

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

I'm still VERY new to Javascript and I'm having trouble with looping through an array and replacing items. I hope this explanation is clear.

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[
  '1:1',   'blah',
  '1:2',   undefined,
  '1:3',   'smith',
  '1:4',   'blah',
  '1:5',   'williams',
  '1:6',   'blah',
  '1:7',   'blah'
]
```

and I have another array that looks like this:

```
[ 
   'taylor', 
   'smith', 
   'williams', 
   'brown'
]
```

I want to replace any value in the first Array that isn't in a `/([0-9]+):([0-9]+)/g` format and isn't found in the second array. So all the "blah" and "undefined" in the first Array should be replaced with `johnson` but the names that match the second Array and the #:# numbers still remain, so the output shows:

```
[
  '1:1',   'johnson',
  '1:2',   'johnson',
  '1:3',   'smith',
  '1:4',   'johnson',
  '1:5',   'williams',
  '1:6',   'johnson',
  '1:7',   'johnson',
]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a simple `if` statement inside a `for` loop to achieve what you are looking for.

```js
var originalArray = [
  '1:1',   'blah',
  '1:2',   undefined,
  '1:3',   'smith',
  '1:4',   'blah',
  '1:5',   'williams',
  '1:6',   'blah',
  '1:7',   'blah'
];

var matchArray = [ 
   'taylor', 
   'smith', 
   'williams', 
   'brown'
];

for (var i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
    var value = originalArray[i];
    //Check if it matches your RegEx
    if (value !== undefined) {
      var doesItMatchRegEx = value.match(/([0-9]+):([0-9]+)/g);
    } else {
      originalArray[i] = "johnson";
    }
    //Check if it is in your second array
    var isItInSecondArray = matchArray.includes(value);
    if (!doesItMatchRegEx && !isItInSecondArray) {
        //Let's replace it with Johnson
        originalArray[i] = "johnson";
    }
}

console.log(originalArray);
```

Comment: I think you need to consider that the original array can contain undefined values and when matching a string to a regex you should use value.match instead of test.

Comment: Or you could just check if array value is not string and skip it.

Comment: There that should do it

Comment: var doesItMatchRegEx = value.test(/([0-9]+):([0-9]+)/g);

TypeError: value.test is not a function

Comment: I accepted an edit, try it again and let us know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the main array `arr` and the array of names `names`, then this should do the trick:

- `arr.map(item => !/([0-9]+):([0-9]+)/g.test(item) && !names.includes(item) ? 'johnson' : item)`

Comment: didn't work. everything still has it's original value

Comment: .map returns a copy, so you should replace the original one with it if you want to change the values of the original array, like so:

`arr = arr.map(item => !/([0-9]+):([0-9]+)/g.test(item) && !names.includes(item) ? 'johnson' : item)`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a functional approach using the map() function of the array. Alternatively could use a filter(), but since you want to replace certain entries the map does it with less steps.

The Array.prototype.map() method takes in a function that will be called on each item in the array, and the return of that function will go in that index of the return.

```
validNames = [‘taylor’...];
numberFormatRegex = /([0-9]+):([0-9]+)/g;

// This function will run on each value in the array, and the RETURN becomes the new value in the array created after mapping
mapFunction = (value) => {
  if(!validNames.includes(value) && !numberFormatRegex.test(value)){
    // only values NOT in the validNames list AND (&&) NOT passing the refer will enter this branch 
    
    return ‘Johnson’;
  }
  // This only runs if the previous return didn’t so it will only happen for valid values

}

// Call map() method with our new function and save result to new array
// note that the inputArray will be unchanged and a new one will be returned and assigned to newArray
newArray = inputArray.map(mapFunction);
```